# Is there a way to set importpath from qml instead of c++

Tags: c++, qt, import, module, qml

I need to set an import path to custom qml modules so they can be imported in qml. I know this can be set using the env variable `QML2_IMPORT_PATH`, however, I want to set it in my application. The issue is, when I call QQmlEngine::addImportPath in c++, it gets run after my qml files. Is there any way to set this import path from a qml file directly?

Comment: What do you mean by "it gets run after my qml files"? Can you execute that code before you load any qml?

Answer (score 0):

You have a bit of a chicken and egg issue there. As @JarMan says, is there a reason why you can't do this in main.cpp before loading your QML?

If not, I don't think you can use the static import system to solve your problem. You'll likely need to use Qt.createComponent() with a string path to your QML and Component.createObject() and/or Loaders with string paths to your QML to achieve dynamic QML component selection/creation.